# Caliburn.micro with multiple ViewModels

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro

I am building an app that can host multiple widgets. The user will be able to add and remove widgets whenever he chooses. How do I compose this in Caliburn.micro since I don't know the number of widgets before hand?

All widgets will be active at the same time.

Any ideas where I should begin with this? I've done several Caliburn.micro apps but none using any form of composition before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Conductor<T>.Collection.AllActive` for this purpose.

See [Screens, Conductors and Composition](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens%2c%20Conductors%20and%20Composition&referringTitle=Documentation) for details.